# connect .mdb to PHP - error HY000 2001

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I am trying to connect .mdb file to php (xampp). 
My .mdb file is in LAN

```
$mdbFilename = "\\\\Hhwsrv\\bcs\\Eder\\HHW_PL1.mdb";
$db_user = "Admin";
$db_password= "";

$con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$mdbFilename; Uid=$db_user; Pwd=$db_password;");

if( !file_exists($mdbFilename) )
{
   die("file doesnt exist!");
}
else
   echo 'File exists<br />';

if( !$con )
{
   die("not connected");
}
else
   echo 'connected to DB';

$tableList = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM kd";

$result = $con_hhw->query($query);

if(!$result)
{
    die("error in query: " . print_r($con_hhw->errorInfo(),true) );
}
else
{
    while( $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ) 
    {
        $tableList[] = $row[0];
        print_r($tableList);
    }
}
```

And im getting this:

**File exists

connected to DB

Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => -2001 [2] => [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access ] ODBC - Cannot establish connection with 'VP Firm 32-BIT'. (SQLExecute[-2001] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260) [3] => HY000 )**

I know the `VP Firm 32-BIT` is a DOS(!) program for manage this .mdb file.
There is no other logins or passwords when im using access. Maybe there are some stored procedures? But if there are some, how can i check it or how can i add it to query/connect in PHP ? Or maybe there is something else? Or maybe i can do something different to get to .mdb file via PHP?Or i dont know what else... so confused

Comment: Does _VP Firm 32-BIT_ have an exclusive lock on the table? If the database is locked by another program, there's no way to work with it unless you stop that program from locking it (and even if there was, you'd probably risk data corruption in doing so).

Comment: hmm... but i can use MSAccess to enter the .mdb file and its ok. There is no errors in select/insert/update/delete.

Comment: Ah, you can try the more modern `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` driver. Just replace `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` with that.

Comment: When im changing to `...(*mdb, *.accdb)...` im getting Fatal Error and thats it :(

Comment: Try to remove DBQ=$mdbFilename; Uid=$db_user; Pwd=$db_password;

Comment: the same, nothing changed just "Fatal error on line 5". Maybe i should add something in php.ini ? im using xampp

Comment: Ok, i didnt have installed this newer driver. I did it now but error is the same... connection to "VP Firm 32-BIT" failed.